# Return integer to 0 once specified max number is reached?

Tags: vb.net

Is this possible? I want my integer to have a max of 9999 and then return to 0.

So if I do 9997 + 5 the answer would be 2, or even better 3(skip the 0).

Is there a better way of doing this other than looping the addition and checking if the number is 9999 already so I can manually set it back to 1?

Comment: a method to increment and check the value against the max is all you need

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks, I just let the number go above 9999 then check if it's greater than 9999 and subtract 9999 from it.

Comment: @crimson What if they number you end up with is say, 20000? Then your method wont work unless you check it in a loop. The mod operator removes the need for all the checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Modulus operator like this:

```
(9997 + 5) Mod 9999
```

That expression will return `3` like you want.

[Read more about the Mod operator here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx)